# Convert String as Property

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom

```
 var listType = document.getElementById('ddlLists').value;
```

"ddlLists" is an Id for a dropdown list and "listType" variable is having the selected dropdown list item as string type. i want that the "listType" variable as a Type.. as

```
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.listType);
```

i.e.;

```
if listType ="GenericList";
```

i want it act as

```
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.GenericList);
```

but in my code

```
 var listType = document.getElementById('ddlLists').value;
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.listType); 
it is acting as 
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType."GenericList");
```

hence the above my code is giving exception.... please help to sort it out

Comment: its ``SP.ListTemplateType["GenericList"]``

Comment: Use this code to converet Enum.GetName(typeof(SPListTemplateType),listType)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use capital "G"

```
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
```

Or:

```
listCreationInfo.set_templateType(100);
```

You can find all the [SP.ListTemplateType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245053.aspx) enumerations on msdn